# What should be the rdns? Hostname or mail.domain.com

Tags: dns, hotmail

Hotmail sends my email to junk folder. I want to correct this situation. First I checked my reverse dns record. My rdns is mail.domain.com When I test with mxtoolbox it gives an error "Reverse DNS does not match SMTP Banner". My smtp banner is my hostname.

I can define only one banner for smtp.

If I can not define a smtp banner for each domain, should I equal all of my rdns to hostname?

Comment: this is off-topic here - it's not programming related

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, yes, set your reverse DNS equal to your hostname.

Alternatively, add an additional `PTR` record (and `A` record, if necessary) mapping from your `mail.domain.com` to the server's IP address and vice-versa.  It's a common misconception that you can only have one PTR record per IP address, but AFAIK it's not true.  It won't break the DNS itself, although there is a minor risk that it may confuse systems that aren't expecting more than one.